# How do I check if a powershell script should run on a specific day of the week

Tags: powershell

I receive emails from computers on networks not associated with mine.  The emails indicate success or failure of a job on those machine.  I created a script that checks for those emails, every day, and then I receive notification if I don't hear from a specific machine or if the job failed.

Not all machine run the jobs everyday so I receive notifications that jobs did not run when they are not scheduled to run. I have a config file that contains the names of all the machines I expect to hear from and I add or delete machines as necessary.

My question,
What is a good way to check if a machine is suppose to run the task on specific day(s) of the week.  I want to keep it local to the machine that receives the emails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would change my configuration and store a list of objects containg *Machine* and *DaysOfWeek*. Example:

```
$configurations = @(
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Machine = 'M01'
        DaysOfWeek = [DayOfWeek]::Monday, [DayOfWeek]::Tuesday, [DayOfWeek]::Wednesday
    }

    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Machine = 'M02'
        DaysOfWeek = [DayOfWeek]::Sunday
    }
)
```

Now you can retrieve the current `DayOfWeek` and filter all Machines that runs a job today:

```
$configurations | Where { (Get-Date).DayOfWeek -in $_.DaysOfWeek } | Foreach {
    # Do your stuff here
}
```

You could also save and read the configuration as / from `csv`.

Comment: Outputting a CustomObject is easily the best way to improve script logic.

Comment: Got it to work, had to change DaysofWeek to include -join so that the actual Day of the week was output to the CSV instead of System.Object[]